# Столкнулся с проблемой, когда модель содержит много свойств. Как писать эффективнее?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Дело в том, что впервые столкнулся с моделью, где более 40 свойств, которые нужно отобразить.

```
[Display(Name = "Название 1")]
public string Name1 { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Название 2")]
public int Name2 { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Название 3")]
public int Name3 { get; set; }    
[Display(Name = "Название 4")]
public int Name4 { get; set; }
```

В представлении мне нужно отобразить данные в виде таблицы

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
@Html.LabelFor(c => common.Name1)
</th>
<th>
@Html.LabelFor(c => common.Name2)
</th>
<th>
@Html.LabelFor(c => common.Name3)
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Мне кажется нелогичным такой способ вывода информации и подозреваю, что можно сделать это более легким способом, который пока не смог найти... Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть ли что-либо похожее на это

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
@{
foreach(var DisplayName in Model.ObjectPropertyAttributies)
<th>DisplayName</th>
}
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Есть - называется - рефлексия.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если по работе нужно создавать много однотипных файлов то можно в сторону кодогенерации посмотреть: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Я это использую, чтобы делать заготовки под view model:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="false" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="$(SolutionDir)packages\Prism.Core.6.2.0\lib\net45\Prism.dll" #>

<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="Prism.Mvvm" #>
<#
    // This template generates the code for a ViewModel which is based on some model.
    // Also supposed that used MVVM pattern and Prism Library

   // Full name of type for which will be generated ViewModel
   Type modelType = typeof(someType);   
   PopulateTypeNameProperties(modelType);

   // Namecpase inside which the code of ViemModel will be put
   string space = "Solution.ViewModel";

    // Begining template's code
#>namespace <#= space#>
{
    // usings
    using <#= modelType.Namespace#>;

    public class <#= modelType.Name #>ViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        #region Fields

        <# foreach(var tuple in this.typeNameProperties)
        { #>
private <#= tuple.Item1 #> <#= tuple.Item3 #>;
        <#}#>

        #endregion

        #region Property for binding

        <# foreach(var tuple in this.typeNameProperties)
        { #>
public <#= tuple.Item1 #> <#= tuple.Item2 #>
        {
            get
            {
                return this.<#= tuple.Item3 #>;
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetProperty(ref this.<#= tuple.Item3 #>, value);
            }
        }

        <#}#>

        #endregion

        public <#= modelType.Name #>ViewModel() {}

        public <#= modelType.Name #>ViewModel(<#= modelType.Name #> model) 
        {
        <# foreach(var tuple in this.typeNameProperties)
        { #>
    this.<#= tuple.Item3 #> = model.<#= tuple.Item2 #>;
        <#}#>}

        public void UpdateViewModel(<#= modelType.Name #> model) 
        {
        <# foreach(var tuple in this.typeNameProperties)
        { #>
    this.<#= tuple.Item2 #> = model.<#= tuple.Item2 #>;
        <#}#>}

        public static explicit operator <#= modelType.Name #> (<#= modelType.Name #>ViewModel viewModel) 
        {       
            <# int beforeLast = typeNameProperties.Count - 1; #>
return new <#= modelType.Name #>
            {
        <# for (int i = 0; i < beforeLast; ++i)
        { #>
        <#= typeNameProperties[i].Item2 #> = viewModel.<#= typeNameProperties[i].Item3 #>,
        <#}#><# if (typeNameProperties.Count > 1) 
        {
            this.Write(string.Format("\t\t{0} = viewModel.{1}", typeNameProperties[beforeLast].Item2, typeNameProperties[beforeLast].Item3));           
        }
        this.Write("\r\n");
        #>
            };
        }
    }
}
<#
    // Ending template's code
 #> 
<#+
  // The storage for couple type - name of Properties
  private List<Tuple<string, string, string>> typeNameProperties = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

  private void PopulateTypeNameProperties(Type modelType)
  {
    foreach (var p in modelType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (string.CompareOrdinal(p.Name, "ErrorMessage") == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        string type = GetShortTypeName(p.PropertyType.Name);                    

        var name = p.Name;
        char firstLetter = name[0];
        var property = char.ToUpperInvariant(firstLetter).ToString() + name.Substring(1);
        var field = char.ToLowerInvariant(firstLetter).ToString() + name.Substring(1);

        typeNameProperties.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(type, property, field));
    }
  }
#>

<#+
  private string GetShortTypeName(string typeName)
  {
    switch(typeName)
    {
        case "Int32":
        return "int";

        / .......

        case "Object":
        return "object";

        default:
        return typeName;
    }
  }

#>
```

Правда есть немного заморочек с отступами, и выглядит не очень читабельно. Но не нужно тратить время на медитативный набор свойств view model. Результат вот такой:

```
namespace Solution.ViewModel
{
    // usings 

    public class CurrencyInfoViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        #region Fields

        private string name;
        private string shortName;
        private DateTime modifyTime;        
        private int id;

        #endregion

        #region Property for binding

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetProperty(ref this.name, value);
            }
        }

        public string ShortName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.shortName;
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetProperty(ref this.shortName, value);
            }
        }

        public DateTime ModifyTime
        {
            get
            {
                return this.modifyTime;
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetProperty(ref this.modifyTime, value);
            }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.id;
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetProperty(ref this.id, value);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        public CurrencyInfoViewModel() {}

        public CurrencyInfoViewModel(CurrencyInfo model) 
        {
            this.name = model.Name;
            this.shortName = model.ShortName;
            this.modifyTime = model.ModifyTime;         
            this.id = model.Id;
        }

        public void UpdateViewModel(CurrencyInfo model) 
        {
            this.Name = model.Name;
            this.ShortName = model.ShortName;
            this.ModifyTime = model.ModifyTime;         
            this.Id = model.Id;
        }

        public static explicit operator CurrencyInfo (CurrencyInfoViewModel viewModel) 
        {       
            return new CurrencyInfo
            {
                Name = viewModel.name,
                ShortName = viewModel.shortName,
                ModifyTime = viewModel.modifyTime,              
                Id = viewModel.id
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ответ на вопрос после значительной правки.

Вероятно, можно написать код, который будет действовать через рефлексию и вытягивать информацию о полях. (Не пробовал, поэтому не знаю, есть ли какие-то подводные камни - но путь выглядит вполне рабочим). Рефлексия - штука небыстрая, поэтому вполне возможно, что овчинка не стоит выделки, я лично не слышал, чтобы кто-то шёл таким путём.

Классический способ - это использование кодогенерации. Правый клик на папке контроллеров в solution explorer, Add - Controller, шаблон "MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework" в котором укажите вашу модель, а студия вам сгенерирует полностью контроллер, содержащий все CRUD методы, а также все необходимые view (и для создания-редактирования, и для списка и для детального просмотра).

---

Ответ на предыдущую версию ответа:

Если вам дали утверждённый макет, в котором таблица на сорок строк - то как бы нелогичным вам это не казалось - нужно взять и заверстать.

Либо вам нужно пойти к проектировщику интерфейса и объяснить ему, что сорок колонок на экране мешают работать, а не помогают. Ну или не дизайнера переубеждать, а руководство.

Это правильное решение проблемы. Нужно начать прорабатывать пользовательские сценарии, смотреть в каких какие колонки нужны. Возможно, что окажется, что и не нужно было столько полей. Это - типичные проблемы энтерпрайза:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моей практике был случай, когда удалось убедить руководство, что не нужно заставлять вводить 96 полей, достаточно всего пяти.

Если же вам аналитики и руководство скажет, что тут только так нужно, чтобы на экране был интерфейс чуть ли не гугл таблиц на экране с бесконечным количеством столбцов, то есть ещё вариант, только они ни разу не простой.

Сделайте интерфейс, который позволяет скрывать/показывать столбцы.

Comment: Сильно извиняюсь за неточную формулировку вопроса, я поправил вопрос. Спасибо за напутствие, приму к сведению.

Comment: @Narrador Не рекомендуются значительные правки вопроса, которые сильно меняют суть вопроса - лучше задавать новый, иначе при каждой правке вы будете обесценивать все ответы. Обновил ответ с учётом правки, вариант с рефлексией попробую сегодня вечером попробовать.

Comment: простите, я новенький и пока не знаю таких вещей. Принял к сведению.

Comment: @AK рефлексия, может, и небыстрая - но ASP.NET MVC **уже** ее использует.

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужен просто цикл по всем свойствам - такой способ есть.

Для начала нужно получить метаданные вашей модели. Если это основная модель страницы, то все просто - это `ViewData.ModelMetadata`.

Если же, судя по таблице, это элемент какой-нибудь коллекции, то получить его метаданные проще через вызов `new ViewDataDictionary<ТипЭлемента>(элемент).ModelMetadata`. Точнее, лучше сначала создать `ViewDataDictionary` вот так: `var data = new ViewDataDictionary<ТипЭлемента>()`, а потом менять ему модель - это немного ускорит работу.

Ну а дальше все просто: у `ModelMetadata` есть все требуемые свойства:

```
<table>
  @{ 
    var data = new ViewDataDictionary<ТипЭлемента>(null);
    <thead>
      <tr>
        @foreach (var propertyMetadata in data.ModelMetadata.Properties) {
          <th>@propertyMetadata.DisplayName;</th>
        }
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in какаяТоКоллекция) {
        data.Model = item;
        <tr>
          @foreach (var propertyMetadata in data.ModelMetadata.Properties) {
            <td>@propertyMetadata.Model;</td>
          }
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  }
</table>
```